# Software Development Methodologies for a single programmer

Tags: methodology

Ive been trying to find an answer to what I thought would be a basic question.

What software development methodologies are relevant for a single programmer.

The only one I can find is RAD.

When I've looked into others such as agile they require a team of people.

Could someone more clued up point me in the right direction.

I am just looking for any methodologies that a single programmer can do so I don't waste more hours trying to find the answers.

Comment: Well, I suppose pair programming is out of the question.

Comment: You could debate if you need a methodology at all.  Being a single programmer you should know if the project is on target or not and how far through the SDLC you are. You could use waterfall, but I think methodologies like Agile, Scrum, XP don't apply in your case.

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it a methodology or just discipline but I try to treat my future self as a (not very bright) co-worker and leave him lots of information about what I'm doing.  Also, protect him from dumb mistakes by having good SCM, prototypes, backups....

Comment: Thanks all, very informative. I think i know what needs doing now. I'm going to go down the "treat myself as a (not very bright) co-worker" route.

Comment: You can still pair program, just talk to yourself when you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development methodologies like agile can be applied in almost any context, including going "solo". You just have to take the best out of it and apply it to your needs.

For instance as a single programmer you can have a product backlog with your user stories, you can give them story points, plan your sprints, find your velocity, etc.
In the end you'll be more organized and you'll improve your planning skills for sure.
Hey, i'm not saying that you must have daily standup meetings with yourself! :)

This applies to all development methodologies/processes(RAD, DDD, TDD, ...) don't forget they're just ways of doing things.